# Android React Native build fail

Tags: android, react-native, sdk

I create the simple React Native Project.

Step 1.
C:>react-native init AwesomeProject

Step 2.
C:>cd AwesomeProject

Step 3.
C:>react-native run-android

After that I faced the following error.

```
C:\Users\Smith\AwesomeProject>react-native run-android
Scanning 575 folders for symlinks in C:\Users\Smith\AwesomeProject\node_modul
es (13ms)
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat install
Debug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> The SDK directory 'C:\Users\Smith\AwesomeProject\android\C:UsersSmithApp
DataLocalAndroidsdk' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.774 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Android sdk path in your enviroment is not correct.

Comment: Where can I check this.

Comment: Your sdk path is ` 'C:\Users\Smith\AwesomeProject\android\C:UsersSmithApp
DataLocalAndroidsdk'`, it's not a valid value